# Problema filtrado selectivo por en tabla de Angular Material usando: "filterPredicate". Cannot set property 'filterPredicate' of null

Tags: angular

Tengo un problema de filtrado selectivo por campo específico en una tabla de Angular Material usando: "filterPredicate". Tengo un error: "Cannot set property 'filterPredicate' of null".

Estoy intentando hacer un filtrado específico por campo en una tabla de angular material. Pero me da el error indicado arriba:

Este es el código del componente. Intento hacer un filtrado por el campo "nombre_autor".

```html
  ngOnInit(): void {


    this.miservicio.retornar2().subscribe( data => {

      this.autores = data;

      console.log(this.autores);

      //ordenamos autores

      this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: ShirtId, filter: string) => {
        return data.nombre_autor == filter;
       };
      

      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ShirtId>(this.autores);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      
    });  
    
    
  }

    filtrar(event: Event) {
      const filtro = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
      console.log("el filtro es este " + filtro);
      this.dataSource.filter = filtro.trim().toLowerCase();
            
    }
```

2ª EDICIÓN: Finalmente he dejado el código así, pero no funciona, no filtra el datatable.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {


this.miservicio.retornar2().subscribe( data => {

  this.autores = data;

  console.log(this.autores);

  //ordenamos autores

  
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ShirtId>(this.autores);
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

  this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: ShirtId, filter: string) => {
    return data.nombre_autor == filter;
  
   };

  
});
```

}

```
filtrar(event: Event) {
  const filtro = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
  console.log("el filtro es este " + filtro);
  this.dataSource.filter = filtro.trim().toLowerCase();
  console.log(this.dataSource.filteredData);

   //this.dataSource.filter = filtro.trim().toLowerCase();
   
}
```

En console.log(this.dataSource.filteredData) no me filtra nada, no me imprime nada.

Comment: Debes de inicializar dataSource antes de poder utlizar la propiedad `filterPredicate`. Y lo estas poniendo antes de iniciailzarlo.

Comment: Ok gracias. de todas foromas no entiendo bien cómo funciona "filterpredicate", porque yo le paso dos parámetros "data", que es un objeto con propiedades y un "filter", que es un string. Luego la función devuelve algo, pero no sé el qué... tampoco sé cómo pasarle el parámetro "filter: string" para poder customizar ese "filter" y que lo pille de una caja de texto en la plantilla

Comment: te lo escribo como respuesta con los link necesarios para comprenderlo

Answer (score 0):

Si tiene ese comportamiento es porque se definió a

```
  filterPredicate: (data: T, filter: string) => boolean
```

la  cual retorna un booleano de acuerdo a la coincidencia o no de la búsqueda por lo cual basta con quitarlo para que vuelva a tener el comportamiento por default asi podriás filtrar por cualquier campo ejemplo comportamiento default---> [filter](https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/angularya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=48&codigo=48&inicio=40)
Si quieres filtar por nombre de autor aplicando un filtro selectivo:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.datos()
    this.filtroTabla();
  }
    filtroTabla(){
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: ShirtId, filter: string) => {
        return data.nombre_autor.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filter);
   }
}
```

Podes consultar teoria en este link-->[filerPredicate](https://www.angularjswiki.com/material/mat-table-filterpredicate/)

```
datos(){
this.miservicio.retornar2().subscribe( data => {

  this.autores = data;

  console.log(this.autores);

  
  
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ShirtId>(this.autores)
}
}
```

;Otro ejemplo en este te indican como llamar adecuadamente desde ngOnInit() a los datos que inician la tabla y también desde ahi  al filtro especifico y como tener en cuenta a la paginación en el metodo filtrar

```
applyFilter(event: Event): void {
    const filter = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filter;
    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
```

-->[filtro por columna especifica](https://decodedscript.com/angular-material-table-filter-by-columns/)